# In search of a unified theory for the interpretation of |, <Bar>, and \| in Vim

Tags: vim

Here are a few experiments to demonstrate how `|`, `<Bar>`, and `\|` behave in different scenarios in Vim commands.

The code-blocks below show several Vim commands with each command (or set of commands) followed by a quick commentary on how the command behaves.

#### Case 1: Shell commands

```
:!uname | new
/bin/bash: new: command not found

:!uname <Bar> new
/bin/bash: Bar: no such file or directory

:!uname \| new
usage: uname [-amnprsv]

:!uname | grep i
Darwin
```

Conclusions:

- `|` is passed as literal `|` to the shell.
- `<Bar>` is passed as literal `<Bar>` to the I/O redirection.
- `\|` is passed as literal `|` to the shell.

So in this case, all three commands behave similarly, in the sense that, what you see is what is passed to the shell. So this is easy to understand.

#### Case 2: User-defined commands for shell commands

```
:command! A !uname | new
:A
/bin/bash: new: command not found

:command! A !uname <Bar> new
:A
/bin/bash: new: command not found

:command! A !uname \| new
:A
usage: uname [-amnprsv]

:command! A !uname | grep i
:A
Darwin

:command! A !uname <Bar> grep i
:A
Darwin
```

Conclusions:

- `|` and `<Bar>` behave similarly (passed as `|` to the shell).
- `\|` behaves different (passed as literal `\|` to the shell).

#### Case 3: Maps for shell commands

```
:map ,a :!uname | new<CR>
,a
Creates a new window when the `:map` command is executed.
Enters `!uname` in the command-line-mode when `,a` is pressed.

:map ,a :!uname <Bar> new
,a
Enters `:!uname | new` in the command mode.

:map ,a :!uname \| new
,a
Enters `:!uname | new` in the command mode.
```

Conclusions:

- `|` behaves different (command separator between `:map` and another Vim command, `new` in this case).
- `<Bar>` and `\|` behave similarly (they become `|` when the map-rhs is executed).

#### Case 4: Vim commands that accept arguments

```
:new | vnew
Creates split windows

:new <Bar> vnew
Creates a single split window with file named `<Bar> vnew`

:new \| vnew
Creates a single split window with file named `| vnew`
```

Conclusions:

- `|` behaves different (as command separator).
- `\|` and `<Bar>` behave similarly (as literal argument).

#### Case 5: User-defined commands for Vim commands that accept arguments.

```
:command! A new | vnew
:A
Creates split windows.

:command! A new <Bar> vnew
:A
Creates split windows

:command! A new \| vnew
:A
Creates a single split window with file named `| vnew`
```

Conclusions

- `|` and `<Bar>` behave similarly (as command separators during command runtime).
- `\|` behaves differently (as literal argument to `new` during command runtime).

This is consistent with Case 2 above.

#### Case 6: Maps for Vim commands that accept arguments.

```
:map ,a :new | vnew
,a
Creates a new window when the `:map` command is executed.
Enters `new` in the command-line-mode when `,a` is pressed.

:map ,a :new <Bar> vnew
,a
Enters `:new | vnew` in the command-line-mode when `,a` is pressed.

:map ,a :new \| vnew
,a
Enters `:new | vnew` in the command-line-mode when `,a` is pressed.
```

Conclusions:

- `|` behaves different (command separator between `:map` and another Vim command, `new` in this case).
- `<Bar>` and `\|` behaves similarly (they become `|` when the map-rhs is executed)

This is consistent with Case 3 above. That makes sense because this case is essentially the same as Case 2, i.e., `:map` to remap key-strokes to command-line-mode commands.

#### Case 7: Vim commands that do not accept arguments

```
:bn | bn
Goes to the 2nd next buffer.

:bn <Bar> bn
E488: Trailing characters

:bn \| bn
Goes to the 1st next buffer. What happened to `\| bn`?!
```

Conclusions:

- All three of `|`, `<Bar>`, and `\|` behave differently.

#### Case 8: User-defined commands for Vim commands that do not accept arguments.

```
:command! A bn | bn
:A
Goes to the 2nd next buffer.

:command! A bn <Bar> bn
:A
Goes to the 2nd next buffer.

:command! A bn \| bn
:A
Goes to the 1st next buffer.
```

Conclusions:
- `|` and `<Bar>` behave similarly (as command separators during command runtime).
- `\|` behaves as if `\|` was literally used as `\|` in `bn \| bn` which produces confusing behavior as demonstrated in the previous case.

This behavior is consistent with Case 2 and Case 5.

#### Case 9: Maps for Vim commands that do not accept arguments.

```
:map ,a :bn | bn
,a
Switches to the next buffer when `:map` command is executed.
Enters `:bn` in the command-line-mode.

:map ,a :bn <Bar> bn
,a
Enters `:bn | bn` in the command-line-mode.

:map ,a :bn \| bn
,a
Enters `:bn | bn` in the command-line-mode
```

This is consistent with Case 3 and Case 6 above.

#### My Question

What are the definitive rules (as per an authoritative Vim documentation or reference) regarding how `|`, `<Bar>`, and `\|` is interpreted in various commands assuming default settings of Vim (default `cpoptions`, plain `:map` and `:command` commands, etc.)?

Comment: In Case 1,`<Bar>` is not passed as `|` to the shell, but as `<Bar>`. This attemps a stdin redirect from a file called `Bar`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @L3viathan You are right. Thanks for calling this out. I have fixed the "Conclusions" for this case in my question.

Comment: To the close-voter who voted this question as off-topic: Questions about Vim has always been on topic on Stack Overflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic which says, "... if your question generally covers… software tools commonly used by programmers ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!". Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim.

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question, I have been researching Vim's `:help` to collect as many clues as possible. Here is a theory that almost seems to work. I am including the relevant documentation from Vim's `:help` that I could find to support each point.

1. With `:!`, `|`, `<Bar>`, and `\|` are passed literally to the shell commands.

   ```
                                                           *:!cmd* *:!* *E34*
   :!{cmd}                 Execute {cmd} with the shell.  See also the 'shell'
                           and 'shelltype' option.

                           ...

                           A '|' in {cmd} is passed to the shell, you cannot use
                           it to append a Vim command.  See |:bar|.
   ```
2. Many command-line mode commands (such as `map` but not `:command` nor `:!`) end when `|` is encountered because that's the command separator.

   ```
                                                           *:bar* *:\bar*
   '|' can be used to separate commands, so you can give multiple commands in one
   line.  If you want to use '|' in an argument, precede it with '\'.

   These commands see the '|' as their argument, and can therefore not be
   followed by another Vim command:

       :argdo
       :autocmd
       :bufdo
       :cdo
       :cfdo
       :command
       ...
       :make
       :normal
       ...
       :[range]!
   ```

   It is important to notice in the list above that while `:command` and `:!` consume the `|` as an argument, `:map` does not. This is going to be important in point 4 below.
3. Unless some special behavior is documented regarding `<Bar>` and `\|` for certain command-line mode commands in the documentation, these are consumed literally. This can explain the behavior of `<Bar>` and `\|` in point 1 above. But it fails to explain the behavior of `<Bar>` in point 4 below.
4. With `:command`, `|` and `<Bar>` behave like a command separator within the replacement command text at runtime when the user-defined command is executed.

   ```
                                                           *:bar* *:\bar*

   ...

   These commands see the '|' as their argument, and can therefore not be
   followed by another Vim command:
       :argdo
       :autocmd
       :bufdo
       :cdo
       :cfdo
       :command
       ...
       :make
       :normal
       ...
       :[range]!
   ```

   It is not clear why `<Bar>` also behaves like `|` in `:command` from this documentation.
5. With `:command`, `\|` is passed as literal `\|` argument within the replacement command text at runtime when the user-defined command is executed.

   ```
                                                           *:bar* *:\bar*
   '|' can be used to separate commands, so you can give multiple commands in one
   line.  If you want to use '|' in an argument, precede it with '\'.
   ```
6. With `:map`, `|` is a command separator between the `map` command and a second Vim command. The second Vim command is executed as soon as the `map` command is executed and the user-defined command is defined. It is not executed when the user-defined command is executed. This follows directly from the Vim documentation quoted in point 2 above.
7. With `:map`, `<Bar>` and `\|` behave like a command separator at runtime of the user-defined command.

   ```
                                                           *map_bar* *map-bar*
   Since the '|' character is used to separate a map command from the next
   command, you will have to do something special to include  a '|' in {rhs}.
   There are three methods:
      use       works when                    example      ~
      <Bar>     '<' is not in 'cpoptions'     :map _l :!ls <Bar> more^M
      \|        'b' is not in 'cpoptions'     :map _l :!ls \| more^M
      ^V|       always, in Vim and Vi         :map _l :!ls ^V| more^M

   (here ^V stands for CTRL-V; to get one CTRL-V you have to type it twice; you
   cannot use the <> notation "<C-V>" here).

   All three work when you use the default setting for 'cpoptions'.
   ```

   Also,

   ```
                                           *key-notation* *key-codes* *keycodes*
   These names for keys are used in the documentation. ...

   ...

   <Bslash>        backslash               \        92     *backslash* *<Bslash>*
   <Bar>           vertical bar            |       124     *<Bar>*
   <Del>           delete                          127

   ...

   For mapping, abbreviation and menu commands you can then copy-paste the
   examples and use them directly.  Or type them literally, including the '<' and
   '>' characters.  This does NOT work for other commands, like ":set" and
   ":autocmd"!
   ```

   Also,

   ```
   SPECIAL CHARACTERS

   The ":map" command can be followed by another command.  A | character
   separates the two commands.  This also means that a | character can't be used
   inside a map command.  To include one, use <Bar> (five characters).  Example:

       :map <F8> :write <Bar> !checkin %:S<CR>
   ```

Behavior that still remain unexplained:

- Why does `<Bar>` behave like `|` in `:command`? (Note that `<Bar>` is passed literally as `<Bar>` to the shell in `:!` command. I don't see why it should behave like `|` in `:command`.)